# Files on Google Drive giving API error. Need “Drive Realtime API data” associated with the old file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-contacts-api

I am regular user of Mindmup on google drive , a top rated mind mapping tool on Google drive marketplace.

I have an 2016 Mindmup which I am not able to open. Mindmup said they can help if google can provide “Drive Realtime API data” associated with the old file.

Google has a note that claims that read only access should continue, which is not true. And the link to how to "export realtime API data" is broken.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, as the Google Realtime API has been deprecated, this isn't something the Stack Overflow community can help with.*

#### What You Can Do:

From here, your best bet is to contact Google directly and see if they can provide you with the respective API data that you need. There is still a [cached version of the API reference on Google Search](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:H5DXQvXkSvIJ:https://developers.google.com/realtime/overview%3Fhl%3DES+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=es) which you can access, which may have links to the correct pages you are looking for.

Google Support can be contacted [here](https://support.google.com/), though I feel for this it may be more helpful for you to contact G Suite Support directly. You'll need to follow the corresponding link to you account on [this page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) and contact them this way.

#### References:

- [Cache of Google Realtime API Reference](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:H5DXQvXkSvIJ:https://developers.google.com/realtime/overview%3Fhl%3DES+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=es)
- [Google Help](https://support.google.com/)
- [Contact G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)